# Flask - Periodic Check on Server Side

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm trying to develop some session management for my project. Essentially, I want to check every so often that the subtracting the last request time from a session (stored as a value in a dictionary against a key of the session name) from the current time is below a certain threshold, else destroy the session.

What would be the best way around starting to tackle this, or best practice?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timeout value for the flask session.
Below code is the example for 3 minutes timeout.

```
from flask import app, session 

session.permanent = True
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=3)
```

Comment: Thank you. My project allows files to be uploaded from unauthorised, public users and it will then process them and serve a results file. I create a directory based on the session token name. I ideally want to do it as described in the OP so that when the session has no activity for, say, 30 mins then the session (and the related directory) are deleted.

I found APS (https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which I think might solve my issue :)

Comment: okay. with apscheduler, you can create cron job, or interval job.